# get the name of a track from its id in spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I have found lots of methods to get the id of a Spotify track but I haven't managed to find a method where I can get the name of one, couldn't find anything in the docs, or I'm just looking in the wrong place. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. How do you have these tracks? Usually something like `track["name"]` should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [track()](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.track) function returns all kinds of information about a track in JSON format. To access the name, simply do something like:

```
track = 'spotify:track:0Svkvt5I79wficMFgqEQJ'
track = sp.track(track)

print(track["name"])
```

Comment: thank you! i dont know why i didnt think of this